# How can I upload a file in an ASP site? (NOT ASP.NET & NO DLL)

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I want a simple method to upload file in ASP.
Just one function

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** from the downvote, I realize that you ask for a no DLL answer, for that, you should look at a [Pure ASP Upload](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pure-asp-upload.htm) or [check out this article](http://www.asp101.com/articles/jacob/scriptupload.asp)

Better yet, [google for "Upload pure vbscript"](http://www.google.com/search?q=upload+pure+vbscript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)

But, a more common, tested, with better performance solution is installing a third party library.
I like [AbcUpload from WebSuperGoo](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcupload-1.htm) (free with LinkBack license)

### basicupload.htm

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="basicupload.asp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filefield"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

### basicupload.asp

```
<% @Language="VBScript" %>
<%
Set theForm = Server.CreateObject("ABCUpload4.XForm")
theForm.Overwrite = True
If theForm.Files("filefield").FileExists Then
   theForm.Files("filefield").Save "myupload.dat"
End If
%>
<html>
<body>
File uploaded...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: [Microsoft Post Acceptor](http://www.dataaccess.com/whitepapers/postingacceptor/UsingMSPostingAcceptor.html)